# How to access Hive Tables from Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have setup a hive datamart and using spark framework to query the table and perform ETL activities , now I want users to access the hive tables by connecting from their local machine and the query should use the spark framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various methods that you can follow to connect to Hive metastore or access Hive tables from Apache Spark processing framework.

Below are some of commonly used methods to access hive tables from apache spark:

- Access Hive Tables using Apache Spark Beeline
- Accessing Hive Tables using Apache Spark JDBC Driver
- Execute Pyspark Script from Python and Examples

Please follow this link to understand in detail:http://dwgeek.com/methods-to-access-hive-tables-from-apache-spark.html/

Comment: Thanks @Vin I was able to setup spark thrift server to access hive table using spark framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into [Hive on Spark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started).

When you will have configuration for that service (explained on linked website), users will be able to write query on Hive Editor e.g on Hue, but Spark will be used underneath to provide results.
Users may change engine of theirs queries like that

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
```

Comment: Thanks #Lukasz for the repy but mapR distribution doesn't not support below properties: set hive.execution.engine=spark; but I was able to setup spark thrift services.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I wasn't aware that mapR is not supporting that.